# Which relative pronoun is correct and why?

Tags: pronouns

There are 2 statements. I am not sure which one is right.

**Who** does this pen belong to?

To **whom** does this pen belong?

Please explain both according to British grammar especially according to relative pronoun?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the second is correct (BTW they're questions, not statements). However, no-one would ask such a question in ordinary conversation unless they were using very formal language for fun.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043658/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/who-or-whom)